# Search for field name in access table then update relevant fields names with values delphi 7

Tags: ms-access-2010, delphi-7

I have an Access database table named `ReceiptTable` with the following field names: `item name`, `buying price`, `selling price`, `goods total`, `cash`, `change`. I am using an Adoquery and datasource to connect to the access database. When I want to update records to receiptTable, I use the following code to locate an `item name` from the database then update all the records with similar item name in the database with  the values from edit box field values:

```
procedure TReceiptForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ADOQuery1 do
ADOQuery1.Open;
ADOQuery1.Locate('item name',Edit1.Text,[]) ;
ADOQuery1.edit;
ADOQuery1.FieldValues['goods total']:=edit3.Text;
ADOQuery1.FieldValues['cash']:=edit4.Text;
ADOQuery1.FieldValues['change']:=edit5.Text;
ADOQuery1.Post;
end;
```

The problem I have is that only one row with the `item name` is updated but the other rows with similar item name are not updated. What code should I add above so that all the rows which have similar item names are updated with values from edit boxes?

Comment: Why not use a simple `UPDATE ... WHERE ... ` SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code answers your question:

```
procedure TReceiptForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    itemname, goodstotal, cash, change: string;
begin
    // Execute query
    try
        ADOQuery1.Open;
    except
        on E: Exception do begin
            ShowMessage(E.Message);
            Exit;
        end{on};
    end{try};
    // Values
    itemname   := Edit1.Text;
    goodstotal := Edit3.Text;
    cash       := Edit4.Text;
    change     := Edit5.Text;
    // Find first matching record, then go to the end of resultset.
    try
        ADOQuery1.DisableControls;
        if ADOQuery1.Locate('item name', itemname, []) then begin
            while not ADOQuery1.Eof do begin
                if ADOQuery1.FieldByName('item name').AsString = itemname then begin
                    ADOQuery1.Edit;
                    ADOQuery1.FieldValues['goods total'] := goodstotal;
                    ADOQuery1.FieldValues['cash']        := cash;
                    ADOQuery1.FieldValues['change']      := change;
                    ADOQuery1.Post;
                end{if};    
                ADOQuery1.Next;
            end{while};
        end{if};
    finally
        ADOQuery1.EnableControls;
    end{try};
end;
```

This will work, but you can consider using one SQL statement for updating the table, or 
if it is possible order your query by `'item name'` and use this:

```
...
// Find first matching record, then update while next record matches too.
if ADOQuery1.Locate('item name', itemname, []) then begin
    while (not ADOQuery1.Eof) and 
          (ADOQuery1.FieldByName('item name').AsString = itemname) do begin
        ADOQuery1.Edit;
        ADOQuery1.FieldValues['goods total'] := goodstotal;
        ADOQuery1.FieldValues['cash']        := cash;
        ADOQuery1.FieldValues['change']      := change;
        ADOQuery1.Post;
        ADOQuery1.Next;
    end{while};
end{if};
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I sorted the table and I have used the last code and it has worked perfectly. Many thanks and blessings. :-))